# How to insert multiple records in multiple table using PreparedStatement object in java?

Tags: java, sql, mariadb

I want to insert two different rows on two other tables. How can I do that? I have read about batch execution but do not understand it clearly. If it is possible to use batch execution, how?

I have tried this way and got this message "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' at line 1
". Thanks in advance.

```
/**
     * save data from multiple tables
     */
    private void customSave() {
        // create connection
        conn = new DB_Connection().makeConn();

        try {

            // for invoice table
            String product_name = comboProductName.getSelectedItem().toString();
            String date_of_sale = textDateOfSale.getText();
            String paid_on = textPaidOn.getText();
            int quantity = Integer.valueOf(spinnerQuantity.getValue().toString());
            int discount = Integer.valueOf(textDiscount.getText());
            double total_price = Double.valueOf(lblTotal.getText());

            // for customer details table
            String name = textFullName.getText();
            String email = textEmail.getText();
            String mobile = textMobile.getText();
            String address = textAddress.getText();

            stmnt = conn.createStatement();

            // save to invoice
            String sql_invoice = "INSERT INTO `invoice`(`product_name`, `date_of_sale`, `paid_on`, `discount`, `total_price`, `quantity`) "
                    + "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
            ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql_invoice);
            ps.setString(1, product_name);
            ps.setString(2, date_of_sale);
            ps.setString(3, paid_on);
            ps.setInt(4, discount);
            ps.setDouble(5, total_price);
            ps.setInt(6, quantity);

            // save to customer_details
            String sql_customer = "insert into customer_details(customer_name, email, mobile, address )"
                    + "values (?, ?, ?, ?)";
            ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql_customer);
            ps.setString(1, name);
            ps.setString(2, email);
            ps.setString(3, mobile);
            ps.setString(4, address);

            if ((!textDateOfSale.getText().equals("")) && (!textPaidOn.getText().equals(""))
                    && (!textFullName.getText().equals(""))) {

                int count = ps.executeUpdate(sql_invoice);
                int count1 = ps.executeUpdate(sql_customer);

                if (count > 0 && count1 > 0) {

                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Data saved successfully.", "Success!!!",
                            JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                    textDateOfSale.setText("");
                    textPaidOn.setText("");
                    textFullName.setText("");
                    textEmail.setText("");
                    textMobile.setText("");
                    textAddress.setText("");
                } else {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Unable to save data.", "Warning!!!",
                            JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                }
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please fillup the required fields.", "Warning!",
                        JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
            }

            stmnt.close();
            conn.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            // JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex, "Error!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
            ex.getStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: The two sql statements seem entirely unrelated so I'm wondering why they are even happening together?

Comment: I need to save data into two tables at a time, I saved into one table successfully but I need more than one. Here is the update code: ps.addBatch(); and ps.executeBatch(); But not work.